# Understanding config variables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a database that is hosted on AWS Aurora. Now let's say it has been assigned particular memory, RAM, buffer pool size, etc.

I also have `my.ini` file on my local machine. What happens if I change the pool size to `16M` in `my.ini`? Would that affect the performance of my query when I run on my machine? Or will it still use the buffer size set up in aurora?

My current variables are like this:

```
show variables;
innodb_buffer_pool_size 20915945472
```

Is this number from the aurora? My local `my.ini` file reads like this:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=2.5G
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Settings**

There is a pecking order of what config files are used.  I hesitate to say exactly what Aurora does, since it is offshoot of MySQL.  First will be `/etc/my.chf` of `/etc/my.ini`; last will be `.my.cnf` in your home directory.  (Note the leading dot.)  Later values will override earlier values.

Be sure to put things in the `[mysqld]` group in *each* file.

Be aware that the various settings become visible at different times -- after restart; after re-login; etc.  Also, note that some are "global", some are "session" (and initialized to the global value); etc.  Also note that some can be changed dynamically with a `SET` command; but, again, there are various variants due to global/session.

**Buffer_pool**

The main use of memory is for the buffer_pool.

- Bigger = faster
- Too big --> swapping, and slowdown, or even crash

The default for Aurora is *probably* optimal for the amount of RAM in the server.  Do not change it.  In the absence of a decent default, set it to about 70% of available RAM for MySQL.

Comment: But what about the my.ini file number? What if I change that to let's say 16M? Will it still use the Aurora settings?

Comment: @Hello.World - I added to my Answer.  `innodb_buffer_pool` is only global, and (but depending on the version) can only be set in a config file.

Comment: If you are using Engine=InnoDB, 16M for `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is dangerously tiny.  The system is likely to run slowly and possibly crash.